# Backbone: How to save an attribute change of a model right from its collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

This is not so specific but common question about my Backbone architecture understanding.

So I need to edit Product attributes right from the list.
I created a Backbone Model for Product and Backbone Collection for the list of Products.

In the list you can choose any model and system should slide down Edit Interface for this model.

So I launch the view where I want to render the list and show/edit the specific model from the collection:

```
App.Views.ProductList = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#content',
initialize: function() {
    this.render();
},
events: {
    'click #show': 'show', // to show model interface in the list
    'click #save': 'save'  // to save model changes in the list
},
show: function(e) {
    var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
    $('#product' + id).slideToggle();
},
save: function(e) {
    var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
    var form = $('#product' + id + ' form');
    var model = this.collection.at(id);
    model.set(form.serializeJSON());
    model.save({
        url: '/product'
    });
},
render: function() {
    var template = _.template($('#productList').html());
    this.$el.empty().append(
        template({
            products: this.collection.toJSON()
        })
    );
    return this;
}
```

});

So, guys, Im sure that in the way of updating a model from its collection Im going with very very wrong pattern. I think collections are able to listen to changes of collection models.

The way I choose `model.save()` uses collections url not models url and I cant override collections url. Please, explain how you would solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem described in the end was cos of in the model I define url not urlRoot.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I always like to do to avoid problems like these is to create a "list view" and an "item view", and render multiple item views on the list view. This allows me to have two separate events hashes: One at the item view level, and one at the list view level. Doing this also makes it obvious where Backbone event handling should go (item view if we are focused on one model, list view if we are focused on the collection).

Remember also that Backbone collections proxy all model events to their own event triggers, so it becomes possible to do `collection.on("change:someModelAttr")`. All of those callbacks will get the model that was affected, too.

Comment: creating list and item views - you mean initialize item view right in List view?

Comment: Yes-- you would have two separate `Backbone.View.extend()` objects and you would add new item views on collection `add` events. Slightly more complicated to deal with collection size changes, but much easier to deal with model events.